# Rolling statsmodels cointegration using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, rolling-computation

I have a DataFrame with two Series and I know how to get their cointegration using all data points...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts

A = pd.Series(np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=100)) + 50)
B = pd.Series(A + 5 + np.random.normal(size=100))

ts.coint(A, B)
```

However, I'd like to explore how this cointegration has changed over time by using a rolling window (let's say 60 days). How can I achieve this using a combination of statsmodels and pandas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by first creating a dataframe, assigning an integer-position series, then use pandas `rolling` function with a lambda function that extracts the first element of `ts.coint`'s return.

So modifying your code we get:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts

A = pd.Series(np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=1000)) + 50, name='A')
B = pd.Series(A + 5 + np.random.normal(size=1000), name='B')

df = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)
df['ii'] = range(len(df))

df['ii'].rolling(100).apply(lambda ii: ts.coint(df.loc[ii, 'A'], df.loc[ii, 'B'])[0])
```

To illustrate this, I increased the size of the series to 1000 and set the rolling window  to 100 (but you can play with the options in `rolling`).

Comment: There is no advantage of constructing a dataframe from the input series, because `rolling` does not support multi-column windows.

Comment: Storing ranges in a column just to make rolling work is also a very bad idea. There is a potential risk of going out of memory if series or windows are large enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Series.index.map()` given that both series are of the same length. If series A and B are indexed from 0:

```
C = A.index.map(lambda i: ts.coint(A[i-60:i], B[i-60:i])[0] if i >= 60 else np.nan)
```

If the series indexes are something else (ie. datetime) you need to reset the index first and use `iloc` for positioning:

```
C = A.reset_index().index.map(lambda i: ts.coint(A.iloc[i-60:i], B.iloc[i-60:i])[0] if i >= 60 else np.nan)
```